# Get the largest element at the property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get the largest element in the given array and the following are the requirements:

- If the array is empty, it should return undefined.
- If the property at the given key is not an array, it should return undefined.
- If there is no property at the key, it should return undefined.

  var obj = {
    key: [1, 2, 4]
  };

Can someone explain to me why when I put

```
!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)
```

at the end of the **IF** function I get the error: **should return undefined if the property does not exist.** But when I put it in the beginning of the **IF** function, it pass with no issue.

```
var obj = {
  key: [1, 2, 4]
};

function getLargestElementAtProperty(obj, key) {
  if (obj[key].length === 0 || !Array.isArray(obj[key]) || !obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    return undefined;
  }
  var largestElement = 0;
  for (var i in obj[key]) {
    if (largestElement < obj[key][i]) {
      largestElement = obj[key][i];
    }
  }
return largestElement;
}
```

Comment: 0 is probably fine for your case, but in general it's better to set the initial min value to a value from the array (usually the first one). That can also save the check if the array is empty, as getting element from empty array results in undefined.

Answer (score 4):

When `!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` is put at the start of the if statement, if the object does not have the specified key (and so `!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` yields `true`), the other checks will not be evaluated due to [OR short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) (briefly, if any of the conditions evaluate to true, none of the other checks are evaluated since the whole expression will always be true).

However, when placed at the end of the if-statement, `obj[key].length === 0` will be evaluated first. If `obj[key] === undefined`, an error will occur when evaluating `obj[key].length`, since `undefined` does not have a property `length`. Specifically, the error is: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: Thank you so much!